How do I make the unused section of a procedural texture transparent? [SOLVED]
I am wondering how to make this procedural texture's unused (black) parts transparent so that the objects behind it can be seen.
The texture is currently applied to a rectangle mesh and is being used to represent airflow; however, as you can see, I want the black parts of the procedural texture removed so that the air filter and the other objects in the scene are visible. The render engine used in this screenshot is EEVEE.
I am new to shader nodes and have not attempted a solution. I would greatly appreciate any feedback or solutions. Thank you!

UPDATE OF SOLUTION- setting Blend Mode to "Alpha Clip":


All I had to do was go into the Viewport Display section of the Materials tab and under Blend Mode, choose "Alpha Clip." This made the unused sections of the texture transparent in EEVEE, though Cycles always rendered them as transparent.

I had some trouble understanding your node tree, but this shouldn’t be too difficult. It looks like you started off right with the last Mix Shader node before the Output, but you need something to drive the Factor to 1 when the texture is black, and 0 when it is not (or flip the way the materials are connected for the other way around). Using a Math node set to Greater Than with a Threshold of zero, you can connect the texture color to the Value input, and the output will be 1 if the texture is not black. Flip the way the materials are connected to that Mix Shader (I.e. Transparency to the top input socket and the rest of the tree to the bottom input socket), and use the Math node output to drive the Factor.

Thank you for your rapid response. I found the solution of changing the material's viewport display settings from "Opaque" blend mode to "Alpha Clip"

All I had to do was go into the Viewport Display section of the Materials tab and under Blend Mode, choose "Alpha Clip." This made the unused sections of the texture transparent in EEVEE, though Cycles always rendered them as transparent.

If you have resolved your issue yourself, be sure to mark the answer as the solution.

Oh, ye I thought about that but didn’t say anything because I figured it was automatically set in the new EEVEE updates. Sorry.
